# PyQt connect PushButtton to next() slot in a Wizard

Tags: python, pyqt

just created a wizard in PyQt. Now I want to be redirected to the next page by clicking a button. I have read that you need QCommandLinkButton for this. But I can't connect the signal from the button with the slot of the next() function.

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QCheckBox, QGridLayout, QGroupBox,
    QLabel, QLineEdit, QMessageBox, QRadioButton, QVBoxLayout, QWizard,
    QWizardPage, QPushButton, QCommandLinkButton)
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSlot

from ClassWizard import *

class Hauptseite(QWizardPage):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Hauptseite, self).__init__(parent)

        self.setTitle("Hauptseite")


        self.pybutton2 = QPushButton('Transport', self)
        self.pybutton2.resize(100,32)
        self.pybutton2.move(240, 20)        
        #self.pybutton2.clicked.connect(self.next)
       # self.pybutton2.clicked.connect(ClassWizard.next())

        self.cl_button = QCommandLinkButton("Next", self)
        self.cl_button.clicked.connect(QWizard.next)
         
    
    
    def nextId(self):
            return ClassWizard.Saegen
```

Comment: TYPO: change  `QWizard.next` to `self.next`

Comment: Dosen't work. AttributeError: 'Hauptseite' object has no attribute 'next'

Comment: `connect(self.wizard().next)`.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but: self.cl_button.clicked.connect(self.wizard().next)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'next'

Comment: @JanikWeis QWizard already provides buttons for navigation, why do you need to create a new one? In any case, if you're trying to return to the beginning of the wizard (as suggested in a previous comment), be aware that I was wrong about reimplementing `nextId()` (sorry, I didn't remember how QWizard worked), and you can use `restart()` to go to the beginning (but it will reset all previously set fields). Do note that if you only need a "multipage" layout, you don't need QWizard, and a simple QStackedWidget with buttons to change its pages is usually enough.